# lineEdit does not represents the text after calling setText from different Widget over a signal

Tags: qt, qt5

I have one `QWidget (keyboardW)` and one `QDialog (pacsD)` that are implemented separately and both are opened/represented at the same time on my `QMainWindow` if I triggers a `QPushButton` on my `QMainWindow`. The `keyboardW` represents a virtual keyboard and `pacsD` contains some `QLineEdit's` that shall be filled if the user writes something on the keyboard. I implemented the functionality like follow. The problem is: If the `keyboardW` emits the signal with a `QString` the slot `transmitOutputTextSlot()` in the `pacsD` class receives it with the correct content. But the text is not represented on the `lineEdit`. I tried the `setFocus()` and `repaint()` functions. No success.

**KeyboardW.h**

```
namespace int::Mic::Manager {
class PacsD;
class KeyboardW: public QObject, public Ui::keyboardW
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:    
    KeyboardW(QWidget *parent= 0);
    ~KeyboardW();
    QWidget *getKeyboardW(){ return m_KeyboardW; }
signals:
    void transmitOutputTextSignal(QString);
private slots:
    void setTextSlot();
private:
    PacsD *m_PacsD;
    QPointer<QWidget> m_KeyboardW;
    void init();
    QString m_OutputText;
};
}
```

**KeyboardW.cpp**

```
namespace int::Mic::Manager {
KeyboardW::KeyboardW(QWidget *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_KeyboardW = QPointer<QWidget>(new QWidget());
    setupUi(m_KeyboardW);
    init();
}
void KeyboardW::init()
{
    m_PacsD = new PacsD;
    connect(this, SIGNAL(transmitOutputTextSignal(QString)), m_PacsD, SLOT(transmitOutputTextSlot(QString)));
}
void KeyboardW::setTextSlot()
{
    // m_OutputText contains what I have written on the virtual keyboard
    emit transmitOutputTextSignal(m_OutputText);
}
}
```

**PacsD.h**

```
#pragma once
namespace int::Mic::Manager {
class PacsD: public QObject, public Ui::pacsD
{
    Q_OBJECT   
public:
    PacsD(QDialog *parent= 0);
    ~PacsD();
    QDialog *getPacsD(){ return m_PacsD; }
public slots:
    void transmitOutputTextSlot(QString);
private:
    QPointer<QDialog> m_PacsD;
};
}
```

**PacsD.cpp**

```
namespace int::Mic::Manager {
PacsD::PacsD(QDialog *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_PacsD = QPointer<QDialog>(new QDialog());
    setupUi(m_PacsD);
}
void PacsD::transmitOutputTextSlot(QString text)
{
    nameLineEdit->setText(text);
    qDebug()<<"nameLineEdit Text: "<<text;

    // The content of the LineEdit is correcly given
    QString getTransmittedText= nameLineEdit->text();
    qDebug()<<"getTransmittedText: "<<getTransmittedText;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does nameLineEdit->setText() works at some other place at all (i.E. in the constructor)? Is there already text set in the *.ui file for your label?

Comment: Yes, if I set a text in PacsD.cpp's constructor, than it works. As default, the nameLineEdit in *.ui file is empty. But if I set some text, it is then also represented.